# How to draw image from TImage into TListbox?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm trying to create a listbox with images. The images will be fetched from a TImage component ; i don't want to use a TImageList because TImage can handle a lot of image types (png, gif, jpg) and i don't have to convert it to populate the Imagelist.

So i've set my listbox style to lbOwnerDrawVariable and i'm trying to paint the image from TImage into the listbox. I've set Image1 width and height to 50 because this is the size i want the images to have on the listbox.

Here is my code :

```
procedure TForm2.listbox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  CenterText: Integer;
begin
  listbox1.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  listbox1.Canvas.draw(rect.Left+4,rect.Top+4,image1.Picture.graphic);
  CenterText := (Rect.Bottom - Rect.top - listbox1.Canvas.TextHeight(text)) div 2;
  listbox1.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.left + 58, Rect.top + CenterText, listbox1.Items.Strings[index]);
end;
```

But instead of putting the image in each listbox item, it's drawing a lot of images inside thel listbox itself, with its original size instead of 50... what's wrong with my code ?

[image]

Comment: `Image1.Width` and `.Height` are the dimensions of the `TImage` control. These are completely unrelated to the dimensions of `Image1.Picture` (thankfully). You need to stretch draw or pre-scale the image manually. Use `StretchDraw`, for instance.

Comment: Could you please post an example code ?

Comment: Just a comment regarding the first paragraph in your question, the reasoning for not using `TImageList`: **The documentation for `Vcl.Controls.TImageList` says**: *Images in the list may be bitmaps, icons, PNG, GIF and JPEG images: any image type that TImage supports. ImageLists also support 32-bit format, so alpha blended bitmaps and PNG files work properly.*

Comment: Have you considered to use a TVirtualImageList in combination with a TImageCollection?

Comment: @TomBrunberg While techniically `TImageList` does support all the mentioned formats the main problem of `TImageList` is that you are limited to using only one image format at the time. So your ImageList can contain PNG's or JPG's but it cant contain both PNG's and JPG's at the same time. Now why is that? That is because `TImageList` internally store all the images that it contains in one big image often referred as `Atlas Image`. This what OP is referring when he is talking about desire of avoiding the need of converting between image formats.

Comment: @SilverWarior, that's why I suggested TVirtualImageList/TImageCollection. But you are right: In the end any TImageList implementation will need to provide a HIMAGELIST to the Windows control. The advantage of TVirtualImageList is that it scales internally and does that with quite a good quality.

Comment: @UweRaabe TO be hones I haven't used `TVirtuaImageList` or `TImageCollection` yet. When were these even added to Delphi?

Comment: @SilverWarior Delphi 10.3

Comment: @UweRaabe Good to know. I guess I have to reserve some time to study these in order to determine possible advantages and disadvantages so I can determine if it is worth upgrading my projects to use these or leave them using regular `TImageList`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Image1.Width` and `Image1.Height` are the dimensions of the `TImage` control. They have nothing to do with the dimensions of the `Image1.Picture`.

You need to [stretch-draw](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.StretchDraw) the image or pre-scale it.

Just a very quick and dirty example:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.ListBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
begin

  if Control <> ListBox1 then
    Exit;

  if Index = -1 then
    Exit;

  var C := ListBox1.Canvas;

  C.Brush.Color := clWindow;
  C.Font.Color := clWindowText;
  C.FillRect(Rect);

  var R := Rect;
  var S := ListBox1.Items[Index];

  var G := Image1.Picture.Graphic;

  var scale := 1.0;

  if (G.Width > 0) and (G.Height > 0) then
  begin

    var xscale := R.Width / G.Width;
    var yscale := R.Height / G.Height;
    scale := Min(xscale, yscale);

    R.Width := Round(G.Width * scale);
    R.Height := Round(G.Height * scale);

    C.StretchDraw(R, G);

  end;

  R := Rect;
  R.Left := R.Left + Round(G.Width * scale) + C.TextWidth('0');
  C.TextRect(R, S, [tfSingleLine, tfVerticalCenter, tfEndEllipsis]);

end;
```

[image: Screenshot of a form with a TImage and an owner-drawn list box using the TImage's graphic as an icon for each item.]